# Site not loading as expected and showing error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My site is not redirecting as expected. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^admin$ Admin/index.php?qstr=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]
```

http://127.0.0.1/upload/go/2/www.amazon.com : shows error[Not Found The requested URL /upload/go/2/www.amazon.com was not found on this server. ]

http://127.0.0.1/upload/load/2/www.amazon.com : shows error[Not Found The requested URL /upload/go/2/www.amazon.com was not found on this server. ]

Update: I now added following code at the end of my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]
```

But now i am getting error as *The page isn't redirecting properly* in Firefox and *This webpage has a redirect loop* in chrome what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I now added following code at the end of my .htaccess file.
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]`

But now i am getting error as The page isn't redirecting properly in Firefox and This webpage has a redirect loop in chrome 
what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Does your .htaccess file have both the first section and the updated 3 lines above, or are there just 3 lines in it?

Comment: @UlrichPalha It have both first section and these 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try the edited version below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#do not process existing files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^admin$ Admin/index.php?qstr=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Not working. :( same redirect loop error. i dont know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @user269751 Try edited version above - assuming you have not other rules and cutting pasting exactly as is

Comment: This is also not working. Same Redirect loop error. "The webpage has resulted in too many redirects. "